# Request.Form cannot be referred to before being declared

Tags: recaptcha

I have a recaptcha form written in C# and I converted it to vb.net. The C# code works fine, however in my VS when I look at the vb.net program, the word request from:

Dim captchaResponse = **request**.Form("g-recaptcha-response")

is underlined in red, whereas in the C# version it is not underlined with the message: Request.Form cannot be referred to before being declared. Does someone know why this is the case and how I can fix it?

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.IO

Partial Public Class register
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public Function IsReCaptchValid() As Boolean
        Dim result = False
        Dim captchaResponse = request.Form("g-recaptcha-response")
        Dim secretKey = ""
        Dim apiUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}"
        Dim requestUri = String.Format(apiUrl, secretKey, captchaResponse)
        Dim request = CType(WebRequest.Create(requestUri), HttpWebRequest)

        Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Using stream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Dim jResponse As JObject = JObject.Parse(stream.ReadToEnd())
                Dim isSuccess = jResponse.Value(Of Boolean)("success")
                result = If((isSuccess), True, False)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function

    <tr>
                <td align="center">
                   <div id="ReCaptchContainer"></div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Create User" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <table width="55%">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td width="500px">
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblresult" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderRecaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var your_site_key = '6Lf8R04dAAAAALvo5V5rKuxFbRi4sBzWytsXpEFz';
        var renderRecaptcha = function () {
            grecaptcha.render('ReCaptchContainer', {
                'sitekey': '6Lf8R04dAAAAALvo5V5rKuxFbRi4sBzWytsXpEFz',
                'callback': reCaptchaCallback,
                theme: 'light', //light or dark
                type: 'image',// image or audio
                size: 'normal'//normal or compact
            });
        };
        var reCaptchaCallback = function (response) {
            if (response !== '') {
                document.getElementById('lblMessage1').innerHTML = "";
            }
        };
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please post the corresponding C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it resolved on my end. Here's my solution:

```
Public Function IsReCaptchValid() As Boolean
        Dim result = False
        Dim captchaResponse = Request.Form("g-recaptcha-response")
        Dim secretKey = ""
        Dim apiUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}"
        Dim requestUri = String.Format(apiUrl, secretKey, captchaResponse)
        Dim requestt = CType(WebRequest.Create(requestUri), HttpWebRequest)

        Using response As WebResponse = requestt.GetResponse()
            Using stream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Dim jResponse As JObject = JObject.Parse(stream.ReadToEnd())
                Dim isSuccess = jResponse.Value(Of Boolean)("success")
                result = If((isSuccess), True, False)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function
 

    Protected Sub Login1_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles Login1.Authenticate
        If IsReCaptchValid() Then


And on my aspx page:

 <table>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="ReCaptchContainer"></div>
                    <center>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </center>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br /><br />
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderRecaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var your_site_key = '';
        var renderRecaptcha = function () {
            grecaptcha.render('ReCaptchContainer', {
                'sitekey': '',
                'callback': reCaptchaCallback,
                theme: 'light', //light or dark
                type: 'image',// image or audio
                size: 'normal'//normal or compact
            });
        };
        var reCaptchaCallback = function (response) {
            if (response !== '') {
                document.getElementById('lblMessage1').innerHTML = "";
            }
        };
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```